# Looking for a basic C++ library for solving Linear Programs

Tags: c++

Here is what I need:

- A C++ library for solving linear programs. I should be able to invoke a function for solving an LP directly from my C++ code.
- Ideally, the interface should be similar to MATLAB's linprog function that takes as input a matrix A and two vectors f and b, and solves a linear program of the form 
  min fx subject to Ax <= b.

Here is what I don't need:

- Fancy user interface that forces me to describe the LP as a string for some weird reason.
- Mixed Integer Linear Programming. I do not have any integer constraints. I just need a very basic simplex solver.
- High accuracy. If the solution is correct up to two digits of precision, I am happy.
- Anything that is not in C++.

Thanks in advance!!